# SQLite recursive query to get first branch of tree

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, tree, recursive-query

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms application. I have a table in my SQLite database that holds hierarchical data in a tree shape. Let's call it TreeNode:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}
    public string ParentPath { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public int Sort { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

This tree structure holds a huge menu (+100K nodes). Siblings in the tree have a `Sort` value to set an order. The purposes of this property are:

1. That I can show the menu elements in an arbitrary order.
2. That I can calculate a default subtree selection when a node is selected.

Let's focus on point 2. I want to select the first branch until the first leaf considering the `Sort` property.

As an example, let's see the following tree representing the menu (extracted from [here](http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/2012/10/example-recursive-union-tree-traversal.html)) :

```
                               1,0
                                |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    2,1                        93,2                 4,3            5,4       
     |                          |                    |              |
------------------------  ----------------------  ----------------  ----------  
6,5  7,6  8,7  9,8  10,9  11,3  12,5  13,7  14,9  15,1  16,5  17,9  18,2  19,8
      |                                |                       |     |
  ----------                        ----------           ----------  ----------
  27,8  26,9                        25,7  24,8           23,6  22,7  21,5  20,6
```

For each node, first number is the `Id`, second is the sorting for each sibling in the same level. So for node with Id = 2, has Sort = 1, Id = 93 has Sort = 2, etc.

I investigated recursive queries the lasts days and I'm able to traverse the tree top-bottom (breadth-first and depth-first), also I know how to get all the ancestors of a given node. There are tons of examples out there for that.

As I said in point 2, what I want is to have a recursive query that returns me the first branch until the first leaf, or maybe some other condition in the future, but let's stick that I want just the first branch to the first leaf. In the example above the nodes I want to get back from the tree are:

```
1,0
2,1
6,5
```

I tried with a query similar to that:

```
WITH RECURSIVE depth_first_traversal
( 
    level,
    lineage,
    Id,
    ParentId,
    Sort,
    leaf 
)
AS 
( 
    SELECT CAST ( 1 AS INTEGER )    AS level,
        '00' || node.Sort        AS lineage,
        node.Id                  AS Id,
        node.ParentId            AS ParentId,
        node.Sort                AS Sort,
        node.leaf                AS leaf
    FROM node    
    WHERE node.ParentId = 1 --Is NULL 
UNION ALL
    SELECT depth_first_traversal.level + 1,
           depth_first_traversal.lineage || '-' || '00' || node.sibling_number,
           node.node_id,
           node.parent_id,
           node.sibling_number,
           node.leaf
   FROM depth_first_traversal
   INNER JOIN node
   ON node.parent_id = depth_first_traversal.node_id
   --WHERE node.leaf = 1 I was trying to play with a leaf flag to reduce the CTE size
   ORDER BY lineage
)
SELECT 
    node_id,
    level,
    lineage,
    leaf
FROM depth_first_traversal;
```

But this query returns me all the branches from the given node in the initial select. So for the current query it returns me:

```
NodeId    Leaf
2         0
6         1 <- I would like to stop recursivity here, but how?
7         0
27        1
28        1
8         1
9         1
10        1
93        0
11        1
12        1
13        0
25        1
24        1
14        1
4         0
15        1
16        1
17        0
23        1
22        1
5         0
18        0
21        1
20        1
19        1
```

I hope I stated my case clearly, but to summarise,

**my question is**: how can I make a recursive query to get the first branch of the tree given that siblings in the same level are sorted?

The only thing to workaround this problem that I can think of is to post process the given result and make use of a `leaf` flag to stop traversing the query result. But it's far from desirable as the close to the root of the tree the queried node is, the longer the query will take and the bigger the result set will be.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: I add create table and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE node ( 
   Id          INTEGER,
   ParentId    INTEGER REFERENCES node ( node_id ),
   Sort        INTEGER,
   leaf        BOOL,
PRIMARY KEY ( Id ) );

INSERT INTO node VALUES (  1,  NULL,             9, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (      2,  1,             1, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (          6,  2,             5, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (          7,  2,             6, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             27,  7,             8, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             26,  7,             9, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (          8,  2,             7, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (          9,  2,             8, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         10,  2,             9, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (     93,  1,             2, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         11, 93,             3, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         12, 93,             5, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         13, 93,             7, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             25, 13,             7, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             24, 13,             8, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         14, 93,             9, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (      4,  1,             3, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         15,  4,             1, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         16,  4,             5, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         17,  4,             9, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             23, 17,             6, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             22, 17,             7, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (      5, 1,              4, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         18,  5,             2, 0 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             21, 18,             5, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (             20, 18,             6, 1 );
INSERT INTO node VALUES (         19,  5,             8, 1 );
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy copy & pasting into a test database?

Comment: Hi @Shawn, yes, I just added them to the question. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Join the table on itself -> select where parentId joined record is null (this is the first branch) -> rework hierarchic your hierarchic query to start with the record from previous subquery (something like Oracle's "start with" syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to recursively select just the sibling row with the minimum sort value - which is the leftmost child of the current parent row:

```sql
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT Id, ParentId, Sort, 0 as Depth FROM node WHERE ParentId IS NULL
 UNION ALL
  SELECT c.Id, c.ParentId, c.Sort, p.Depth + 1
  FROM node AS c
  JOIN cte AS p ON c.ParentId = p.Id
  WHERE c.Sort = (SELECT min(Sort) FROM node AS t WHERE t.ParentId = p.Id))
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY Depth;
```

```
Id          ParentId    Sort        Depth     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1                       9           0         
2           1           1           1         
6           2           5           2
```